# insert date in MMM YYYY format

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to enter date in format MMM YYYY while creating a table like "Jan 2020".

Comment: Dates consist of a **day**, month and year. `'Jan 2020'` isn't a date, so you can't store it in a date and time data type no. I also suggest against storing such values entirely. Jan 2010 is not after Apr 2020, but `'Jan 2010'` *is* after `'Apr 2020'`.

Comment: Possible? Absolutely. Is it a good idea? absolutely not. Store dates as dates, not as strings.

Comment: Consider a year column and a month column.

Comment: If you need to store a year and month then use a type `Date` and set the day part of the date to the value 1.  Do *not* concern yourself with the perceived format of the column. This will allow for type safety, value consistency, allow you to use built in date functions, and later allow for flexibility in the presentation layer of your application. There are also many existing questions and answers on how to format the returned value depending on your requirements.

Comment: You are missing the day of the month. Without it, it's not a date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never** store *formatted* date values in a database. Really. **NEVER**.

Instead, format date values *as users retrieve them* (in the SELECT clause) or even later (in the client code or reporting tool). If you have data coming into your system in a certain format, *parse it to into a strongly-typed `date` or `datetime` value at the earliest possible moment.*

With that in mind, instead of a `varchar` column to store values like `Jan 2020`,  you want a `Date` column. This gives you a real (complete) date value, where if you only care about the month and year you always use the first day of the month.

Thus, instead of `Jan 2020` you would use `20200101` in the INSERT or UPDATE statement, and Sql Server would efficiently store a binary value.

Now you can use the [`FORMAT()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get Jan 2020 back again, if you need it:

```
FORMAT( MyColumn, 'MMM yyyy')
```

The advantages here are the ability to use these values correctly in an index, do date math (`DATEDIFF()`, `DATEADD()`, etc), letting the database ensure you have real date values, and many more.

Answer (score 3):

**Just saying...** `MMM yyyy` will indeed convert to a date.  However, it will assume the 1st

**Example**

```
select try_convert(date,'Apr 2020')
```

**Returns**

```
2020-04-01
```

**Furthermore**, inserting a `MMM yyyy` string into a `DATE` column works as well

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeDate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Apr 2020')

Select * from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeDate
2020-04-01
```

Comment: Try setting the language to any language that uses other short names for months, such as Spanish, and you'll get null as a result...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed, but sample was in English.  I should have been more clear.  My thinking was that if OP had to consume the string, it is a small matter to store the value as a date (as it should be).    With regards to Spanish,   SET LANGUAGE Spanish  :)